# How to web scrape data which only appears on mouse hover using python beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am working on a project and on this link:
https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/aapl/earnings

I am able to extract all table data easily by normal beautiful soup method. However, on the site, there is a graph, and that data I need only comes when you hover your cursor over it. My issue is simple, how do you extract that? Because when I go to inspect source code of the site on the barchart, I only get the css part of it and the length of the bar and all, not the actual data of estimated and reported EPS which appears on the mouse hover. I wish I could

```
try:
        divparent = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'highcharts-point highcharts-color-0     highcharts-point-mouseOut'})
except:
    print("no table div")
    return
```

I tried to do the code above, but to no avail, and I have literally no idea how to go about this. Any assistance for this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This data is being added to the page using JavaScript, and is not in the response you got with the request to https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/aapl/earnings.

However, you can get it using the API (this is what the JavaScript code does). Just send your get request to: https://api.nasdaq.com/api/quote/AAPL/eps

Comment: can you please elaborate on the API and any documentation for it? and please explain how you managed to generate that api.nasdaq link?